# Weird Error when using SOAP Web Service

Tags: c#, java, web-services, soap

For a school project, I have to create a Java Server that is able to service a .NET client that has a Service Reference to a WSDL. I have the .NET Client code:

```
        using (var client = new MathServiceWSDLClient())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Multiplying " + Num1 + " and " + Num2 + ": " + client.Multiply(Num1, Num2));
            Console.WriteLine("Adding" + Num1 + " and " + Num2 + ": " + client.Add(Num1, Num2));
        }
```

I have also written the Java Server:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());

boolean clientExpectContinue = false;
            int contentLength = -1;
            String line;
            while (!(line = sc.nextLine()).isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.startsWith("Content-Length")) {
                    String[] elements = line.split(": ");
                    contentLength = Integer.parseInt(elements[1]);
                } else if (line.startsWith("Expect")) {
                    clientExpectContinue = true;
                }
            }
            int notEmpties = 0;

            byte[] soapEnvelopeData = new byte[contentLength];
            char[] soapChars = new char[contentLength];
            for (int i = 0; i < contentLength; i++) {
                soapChars[i] = (char) socket.getInputStream().read();
                if (i == 0)
                    System.out.println("DFSDFSDf");
            }

            // System.out.println(socket.getInputStream().read(soapEnvelopeData));
            System.out.println(soapEnvelopeData.length);
            File file = new File("tempEnvelope.txt");
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            // fileOut.write(soapEnvelopeData);
            System.out.println("Content!");
            System.out.println(new String(soapChars));
            fileOut.write(new String(soapChars).getBytes());
            fileOut.flush();
            fileOut.close();
            /* Some fancy SOAP and Reflection stuff that works */
```

The gist of the server is as follows:
   It gets the incomming request, reads through the headers and finds the content length. It parses and saves this. From here there are two versions. The first constructs a byte array the same size as the content length, and passes the array as a parameter into the socket.getInputStream().read() method. The second constructs a char array the same length of the content and then reads individual bytes from the stream and casts them to chars.

The issue comes into play when, as shown, I attempt to run the .NET client with multiple requests in one execution. The first request goes off without any sort of discernible issue. When the second one comes in, the server reads the headers, gets the content length and constructs the array. When it comes time to read from the socket, however, the program just waits. Using the char array method, I was able to learn that it waits when reading the first value. Once one minute has expired, .NET times out, and the rest of the program breaks.

If, however, I leave the server running, and only have one request per execution of the .NET client, everything is just fine; the response comes back just as it should.

I have tried some solutions already:

- Creating a new MathServiceWSDLClient for every request
- Putting every request in its own using() block.
- Doing two of the same request at once: two Multiply() or Add() requests.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you all in advance. 
~Ryno Janse van Rensburg

Comment: Better? Do you have an answer to the issue?

Comment: @rynojvr: there is absolutely no reason for being rude - this just was an important hint!

Answer (score 0):

.net is probably keeping the socket open for subsequent requests. There may be a bug in your server-like java code related to this.

Are you able to use a framework instead for the Java server code? I would strongly recommend this, and recommend rmbedded Jetty without hesitation. This would mean you wouldn't have to work at the socket level in Java - you can let Jetty handle all of that complication.

Comment: At the end of the server code, I close the socket. And like I said, the server gets the headers of the second request, so .NET is at least sending them. 

I would greatly prefer to use a framework, but the point of the assignment to to suffer at the hands of SOAP, and its parsing. My hands are tied into using sockets.

Comment: You have not posted your entire server code so I'm not sure I can help. The framework suggestion was not to remove you from SOAP parsing, you would still have to do that. The idea was to lift you a level away from sockets into servlets. Then you don't have to do all the horrible low level socket and HTTP stuff yourself. Let someone else do that. Jetty will take you half an hour to learn enough to write a simple server. Good luck!